# Where are open Finder windows saved between reboots

Tags: finder

I have had several windows open in the Finder, serving as bookmarks for things I was working on, but recently they have all reverted to my home directory.

I would like to know where these open Finder windows are saved, so that I can look in a copy of that file from a backup, and either restore the file(s) or just retrieve the names from the file(s).

Comment: Are these remote or removable locations? A folder will revert to default if its location is removed.

Comment: No, none of them were removable locations.  (I have no idea how or why they were reset to my home directory.)